# Finding a minimum value from an array - I don't understand

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, minimum

So I know the code below works but as I am very new to coding I don't understand why and how it works. If anyone could explain it to me it would help me forward in understanding programming.

The code is as follows:

```
 public static double minValue(double[] times){  
        double minValue = times[0];  

        for(int i = 1; i < times.length; i++){  
            if (times[i] < minValue){  
                minValue = times[i];  
            }  
        }  
        minValue = minValue / 60;
        return minValue;  
    }
```

What I don't understand here is: `double minValue = times[0];` Why is this value `0`? It works fine with other numbers too, below the length of the array. Using blank or a number greater than array length returns an error but there must be a reason why the code uses specifically `0`.

And then this:

```
for(int i = 1; i < times.length; i++){  
    if (times[i] < minValue) {  
         minValue = times[i];  
    }
}
```

How exactly that determines the minimum value?

Comment: You pick the first element of the array (as starting smallest value), then iterate and check for each element if it is smaller than the currently smallest value. If yes it becomes the new smallest.

Comment: `minValue = minValue / 60;` does not belong there

Answer (score 5):

You have to set some initial value to `minValue`.

One convention is to initialize it to a value larger than all the numbers in the array (such as `Double.MAX_VALUE`).

Then the loop would have to iterate over all the elements of the array :

```
for(int i = 0; i < times.length; i++)
```

Another convention is to initialize it to one of the values of the array (any one will work). The first element of the array is often chosen, which allows the loop to iterate from the second element of the array :

```
for(int i = 1; i < times.length; i++)
```

Comment: If you use the first element as staring value, remember to check that the array is not empty.

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple of things here:

**Why start from times[0]/ Why is this value 0 ???**

The main reason is that arrays in java are **zero based**. This is a term used to indicate that in order to access the first element in the array, you need to access the zero-th array element.

At the same time, this is why you are also unable to access the *nth* item in the array (so if the times has four elements, then the fourth element can only be accessed by `times[3]` and not `times[4]`)

*There is a [very interesting discussion by E.W Dijkstra](http://www.cs.utexas.edu/users/EWD/transcriptions/EWD08xx/EWD831.html) on why this 'should' be the case*

**Programming Example in the Question**

So the programming example is basically, *given an array/list of decimal numbers, find the minimum value within this list*.

If you took the programming language out of the equation here and approached the problem; **one of the ways to solve this** might be the following:

- Start with a default value to be the minimum, here we assume that the first number in our array/list is the minimum.
- Now we go through our array/list of numbers and ask ourselves whether the next number in the array/list is less than our current minimum. If it is less than our current minimum, this number becomes our *new minimum*
- So we do this until there are no more numbers to check.
- By the end of this process, the number that we say is the minimum becomes our result.

**Tying this Information Back to the Code**

So after understanding how we're going to solve this, let's try it with some Java code:

> Start with a default value as our minimum

`double minValue = times[0];`

> Go through the rest of our list

```
for(int i = 1; i < times.length; i++){
```

> Ask ourselves whether the next number in the list is less than the minimum

```
    if (times[i] < minValue){
```

> If it is, then this is our new minimum

```
        minValue = times[i];  
    }  
}
```

> After doing this process with the entire list/array of numbers, you are left with the actual minimum

```
return minValue;
```

Once you have understood that, then you can essentially understand why your code works the way it works (I used your own code too :))

For me the **most important takeaway here** should be that you need to have an idea of how to solve the problem before attempting to use a programming language. A programming language is just used as a way to express the solution you have.

Happy Coding :)

Comment: Thank you! That was a top notch answer that explained everything I asked for in an easily understandable form :)

Comment: @Grv21 No problemo, just keep enjoying your adventures in coding. It will only get better and more interesting from here!

Answer (score 1):

Like many other programming languages, java arrays are indexed beginning at zero. The `[0]` at the end of `double minValue = times[0];` initializes the `minValue` variable to the first element of the array. The `for` loop that follows, begins at the *second* element of the array, i.e. `i = 1`. And it then proceeds to check each value of the array up to the end to see if it's smaller than the smallest value encountered up until that point.

As an aside, the following statement you made is false in the case where the first element of the array is the minimum value:

> It works fine with other numbers too, below the length of the array.

Comment: If I were you, I'd add an example showing why using other numbers in place of 0 is incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

`[0]` means the first value in the `times` array.

At first, `minValue` is set to the first value in the array.
Then, the loop, goes through all the values in the array (except the first one) and checks if any of those is smaller then the current value of `minValue` (previously found smallest value).

`minValue` is reinitialized every time a value from the array is smaller then the current value of `minValue`.

Answer (score 0):

You need `minValue` variable to keep currently the least number. At the beginning you set it to the first element because we have to initialize it somehow. After we start looping every number is compared with it. When the checked element is less than our `minValue` - we change its value. When we finish iterating - we know that our variable stores the minimum.